# How does quickblox api calculate MAU (monthly active users)?

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

I would want to get more details about how monthly active users calculation is done by quickblox, there is no much information available on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Quickblox calculates the MAU based on how many unique user sessions created within that month.

For example,
In June, 100 new users installed your app and logged into Quickblox, which means 100 MAU for June.

In July, 60 new users installed your app. But this time, 30 users who joined in June month left and never used again. So for July month, the MAU is,

**(100-30) + 60 = 130**

Comment: can we also able to get a number of sessions per day in it